# select datatables row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am creating datatables with jquery using:

```
$('#collectionsList').dataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate" : false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "oTableTools": {
        "sRowSelect": "multi"
    },

    "sAjaxSource": serverServicesHandler.get("getCollections"),
        "fnInitComplete" : function(oSettings, json){
    }
})
```

I want a row to be selected when it is clicked on.

I added:

```
"oTableTools": {
    "sRowSelect": "multi"
}
```

but it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: does your `<table>` markup include `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements? And does dataTable otherwise function properly?

Comment: yes I have <thead> & <tbody>, it is created by ajax data

Comment: try the nightly version of TableTools.  I believe that the "stable" version has not been upgraded to deal with the removal of `live()` from jQuery. http://www.datatables.net/download/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the selected rows, I use this click function at the rows :

```
$('body').on("click",'#collectionsList tbody tr',function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('row_selected')) 
    $(this).removeClass('row_selected'); // select or deselect row
  else {
    /* I don't put this line below
    //---> $(this).siblings('.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');
    */
    $(this).addClass('row_selected'); // add selected row
  }
  var aData = oTable.fnGetData(this); // get tha data array from columns
  var col0 = aData[0];  // get the first column value
  var col1 = aData[1];  // get the second column value
  var rowsID=this.id; // rowsID is your id of <tr>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below:

```
 oTable = $('#collectionsList').dataTable( ....);

 $('#collectionsList tbody tr').live('click', function (event) {        
 var aData = oTable.fnGetData(this); // get datarow
 if (null != aData)  // null if we clicked on title row
 {
        //now aData[0] - 1st column(count_id), aData[1] -2nd, etc. 
 }});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery v1.7 and removed as of jQuery v1.9

Answer (score 0):

For TableTools to work you must set `.dataTables.sDom` and include "T" in the string.  Something like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
        sDom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        oTableTools: {
            "sRowSelect": "multi"
        }
});
```